# Wysiwyg with good API

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I'm searching for Wysiwyg that have good API. I want to be possible to hide any tool in toolbox.

I want to be when I click enter I could get it and send content of Wysiwyg to the server.

What Wysiwyg provides such functionality?

Comment: @Mirgorod, could you provide more detail? Is Razor Storm's comment below correct, that you want something you can integrate into you web form application? Could you provide an example of a package that comes close to what you need in some way, and explain what it lacks?

Comment: We use TinyMCE over here, only problem is that with anything like this, you're going to run into bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: I want to be when I click enter I could get it and send content of Wysiwyg to the server.

Comment: Then add a listener for the enter key and add your custom processing. Other people have done it, it's not that hard if you check the API.